# Specify Git repository directory using libgit2

Tags: c, libgit2

By default, when creating a Git repository using `libgit2` a directory named `.git` is created (which contains the repository itself).

Is there a way to specify the directory where the Git repository is contained using `libgit2` (rather than the default directory `.git`)? One workaround would be the creation of a file named `.git` that contains the information of this specific directory but, unfortunately, I cannot use it for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the name of the `.git` directory that is created when you create a new non-bare repository with a working directory.

However, you can create a *bare* repository with any path.  eg:

```
git_repository *repo;
git_repository_init(&repo, "not.git", 1);
```

If you really want a non-bare repository with a particular path that is not `.git`, you can use a work-around, which is to create a bare repository, then open it using the `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables.